# How can I test authentication with Postman if status code is 200 even if I give wrong inputs?

Tags: postman

I'm learning Postman, and I tried authentication with valid and invalid data. (I'm using basic auth).
If I give valid data, the login redirects me to the index page as is should, giving 200 OK status code. However if I pass wrong parameters, the status code remains 200 OK aswell, only the page tells me, that me username and password is incorrect. I tried using the following method I found somewhere:

```
pm.test("Request is successful with a status code of 200", function () {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

I think postman gives me 200 OK since the post-request is done, and the failed-login option is handled properly. (I have to mention that this API I'm testing is pre-defined, I didn't make it.)
So basically how can I test this?

Comment: Once writing test script is completed. export requests as postman collection and use newman to test. 

Follow this doc for more information https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the response body to *not* contain a certain string:

```
pm.test("Body does not contain invalid login message",() => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.text()).to.not.include("invalid login");
});
```

Replace `invalid login` by te string you want to check for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just test for a different status code (i.e., 400  BadRequest)

```
tests["Status code is 400"] = responseCode.code === 400;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.